# Intellij IDEA doesn't detect properties from properties-file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

I've come across one nasty situation and couldn't solve it. I wrote SpringMVC + Hibernate application with Intellij IDEA. I wanna put all my jdbc properties (connection url, username and etc.) in jdbc.properties, but IDEA can't detect them in this file. Here is my WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controllers"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="fileCreator" class="com.utilites.FileCreator"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${jdbc.url}"
          p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <!--<property name="configurationClass">-->
        <!--<value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>-->
        <!--</property>-->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and my jdbc.properties contains:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Overhaul
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=
```

and mysql-dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.32</version>
        </dependency>
```

and my snippet of project structure:
[image]

When I build the project and deploy it, Tomcat shows me this error:

```
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [${jdbc.driverClassName}];
```

What's wrong in my app or somewhere esle?

Comment: I am sure it not Intellij's IDEA problem

Comment: Did you import the driver into your project either from file or in pom.xml? and if so, please show relevant code/file.

Comment: did you declare a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in bean configuration file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the `.properties` file under `resources` and add this above your `bean` definition:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>
</bean>
```